# How do I access the request from the request_finished signal callback?

Tags: django

**How do I obtain and use the HttpRequest using the request_finished signal?**

Interested in extracting the url for logging purposes.

Current code looks something like this:

```
import logging

def write_to_file(sender, **kwargs):
    logging.debug(type(sender))
    logging.debug(dir(sender))

from django.core.signals import request_finished
request_finished.connect(write_to_file)
```

generates this

```
2010-03-03 13:18:44,602 DEBUG <type 'type'>
2010-03-03 13:18:44,602 DEBUG ['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__', '__weakref__', '_get_traceback', 'apply_response_fixes', 'get_response', 'handle_uncaught_exception', 'initLock', 'load_middleware', 'request_class', 'response_fixes']
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can.  Did you trying looking at the keyword arguments dict?  If your just looking to log some information upon every request, you should look into using the Middleware framework http://bit.ly/axVgOj.

Comment: `sender` is the model class, not an instance. If instance data is provided, you will find it in `**kwargs`, however `request_finished` does not include any instance data. You might be able to use the `post_save` signal instead. If you have a time consuming task that you don't want the request to wait for before finishing, run it on a new thread, say `thread.start_new_thread(kwargs.get("instance").do_something_time_consuming, ())`.

Comment: The docs on django state it's a class and not an instance. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#request-finished  Why has a completely wrong answer been accepted?

Answer (score 4):

Django documentation for request_finished state they provide the class not the instance (not sure why, it would have been more useful to provide the instance). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#request-finished

So the signal just let's you know a request has finished, but not which request or any detail of it. You have 2 options to get the request. One, which has been mentioned, is to store the request into thread local storage in a middleware.

Here is an example which stores the request. But you can use it store up functions that will be called at the end.

```
import collections
import threading

import structlog
from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers

logger = structlog.get_logger()

thread_locals = threading.local()


def get_current_request():
    """
    This will return the current request object
    but if the response has been returned the request
    object will be cleaned up
    """
    return getattr(thread_locals, 'request', None)


def request_queue(func, func_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Helper function to queue up a function
    and arguments to be run at the end of the request
    if no request, will run straight away
    Usage:
    request_queue(function_to_run, args=(args1, args2), kwargs={'key':'value'})
    """
    request = get_current_request()
    if not request:
        # run the func
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        return
    # else
    # use the supplied id if given
    if not func_id:
        # otherwise use the memory address
        func_id = id(func)
    # store the func and arguments as a tuple under the func id
    request.queue[func_id] = (func, args, kwargs)


class RequestQueueMiddleware(object):
    """
    Use this middleware to get access to the request object
    and to use it to queue functions to run
    """

    def process_request(self, request):
        thread_locals.request = request
        # each request gets a new queue
        request.queue = collections.OrderedDict()

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        self.process_queue(request)
        self.cleanup()

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        self.process_queue(request)
        self.cleanup()
        return response

    def cleanup(self):
        try:
            del thread_locals.request
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def process_queue(self, request):
        if not request:
            request = get_current_request()
        if request and hasattr(request, 'queue'):
            for (func, args, kwargs) in getattr(request, 'queue', {}).itervalues():
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            del request.queue
```

The function `get_current_request` can be imported and used in any other method when you need access to the current request.

The function `request_queue` allows you to queue up a function and arguments to be executed. A feature is that you could queue up an expensive function many times and it will only be executed once.

So in your `request_finished` handler you can call `get_current_request` to get the current request. But in the above implementation you will need to remove the cleanup code. I don't know if keeping the request object on thread local storage will leak.

The other option which doesn't require any middleware is to inspect the stack frames until you find the request.

```
def get_request():
    """Walk up the stack, return the nearest first argument named "request"."""
    frame = None
    try:
        for f in inspect.stack()[1:]:
            frame = f[0]
            code = frame.f_code
            if code.co_varnames and code.co_varnames[0] == "request":
                return frame.f_locals['request']
    finally:
        del frame
```

If you have any other variable called request it will break. Could be adapted to check type as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found the simplest solution.

Looking through [the official Django rep](https://github.com/django/django), I've found the only use of `requests_finished` [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8c3e0eb1c16abbcded3503b4ea3473b353520f61/django/http/response.py#L252).

Now I can easily override this method in the entry point in `manage.py`:

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseBase

class OverriddenHttpResponseBase:

    @staticmethod
    def close(self):
        for closable in self._closable_objects:
            try:
                closable.close()
            except Exception:
                pass
        self.closed = True
        # here you can access your request using self._closable_objects 

        # you can either send it to request_finished 
        signals.request_finished.send(sender=<whatever data you want>)
        # or code your stuff here without using request_finished at all

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HttpResponseBase.close = OverriddenHttpResponseBase.close
```

Comment: Sounds good.  An improvement might be to inherit from HttpResponseBase and implement a close routine with a call to 'super' then whatever you need to do.

Comment: Calling `super` wouldn't work, as it includes `signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)`. This answer hacks it to replace `self._handler_class`

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
sender.request_class.get_full_path()
```

or

```
sender.request_class._get_request()
```

Or, if you want to try doing this with [middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/), as mountainswhim suggested, here's a [snippet that demos request timing using middleware](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1826/).

Comment: Confused.  Did this answer the OP's question?  Calling any unbound method on the request class only results in complaining about it not having a 'self' argument. (Since, you know, it's unbound.)

Comment: @Chuck yeah, i think it did.  You might have to invoke the `_get_request()` method to get your hands on the instance.

Comment: @Chuck is correct. Calling this unbound method obviously does not work

Comment: guys i ma getting following error `*** TypeError: unbound method _get_post() must be called with WSGIRequest instance as first argument (got nothing instead)` on `dir(sender.request_class._get_post())` any idea why??

Comment: Why the hell is this the accepted answer when it's clearly wrong?! sender is a class and for me it was WSGIHandler. You can see django call it with: `signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)`. The WSGIHandler class doesn't have class level methods. `request_class` property points to another class called `WSGIRequest`. But as stated this is a class so you can't call methods that require self like you've suggested.  So this is just plain wrong.