# Django clear request session value if user navigates away from certain pages

Tags: django, django-sessions

I need to clear request session variable each time user navigates from certain pages.

I was thinking writing my own middleware for such thing and to implement process_request
to clear the variable when needed.

what do you think?

do you know better solution?

would it damage performance instantly?

10x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `request_finished` signal to detect an HTTP request and trigger a function to get the current page's path to check if the user has navigated to a different page. If they have, then you can call `flush()` on the session, or set a specific session var to nil, etc.

Something like:

```
from django.core.signals import request_finished

def check_url(request):
    original_path = '/path_to_original_page'
    if HttpRequest.get_full_path(request) != original_path:
        request.session.flush()

request_finshed.connect(check_url, sender)
```

Take a look at the docs on [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) and [Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) for more information. I don't think writing your own middleware for this is necessary, but choose whatever suits your needs.

Comment: thanks for that.
you're right. mw is overkill signal is better.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but the accepted answer didn't work for me, since you can't get the `request` from `request_finished` (see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368352/how-do-i-access-the-request-from-the-request-finished-signal-callback)).

I ended up creating this simple middleware (similar to the [example in Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware)):

```py
# middleware.py (this is a new file - it could be located in your app directory)

class NewPollSessionCleaner:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if "create_poll" not in request.get_full_path():
            if 'new_poll_title' in request.session:
                del request.session['new_poll_title']
            if 'new_poll_text' in request.session:
                del request.session['new_poll_text']
            if 'new_poll_alternative_count' in request.session:
                del request.session['new_poll_alternative_count']
            if 'new_poll_alternatives' in request.session:
                del request.session['new_poll_alternatives']

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

And this is how your add it into the settings:

```py
# settings.py

MIDDLEWARE = [
    #...
    #... All your other middleware up here
    #...
    # Add new middleware at the end 
    # (Adjust the string to your project layout) 
    "base_dir.app_dir.middleware.NewPollSessionCleaner",
]
```